# Why is SPP20N60S5 rated for more power than STW26NM60N?

Tags: power, mosfet, datasheet

I'm wondering what could be the reason for SPP20N60S5 (PG-TO-220) to be rated for a maximam power of 208W and STW26NM60N (TO-247) only for 140W.

I compared both datasheets and in almost any attribute the STW26NM60N is superior to the SPP20N60S5.

Lets compare important attributes:

| MODEL | ID_MAX | RDS_ON | Q_G | Q_GS | Rthj_case | CASE | P_TOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| STW26NM60N | 20A | 0.165 | 60nC | 8.5nC | 0.89°C/W | TO-247 | 140W |
| SPP20N60S5 | 20A | 0.19 | 79nC | 21nC | 0.6°C/W | PG-TO-220 | 208W |

What could be the reason for SPP20N60S5 rated for 1.5 times the maximum power?

Only information I could found on PG-TO220 is [here](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/packages/PG-TO220/PG-TO220-3-1/) Maybe the difference is another compound in the epoxy it self? That would be the only reason I could imagine for slightly better Rthj_case.

Comment: Have you compared teh thermal performance of the different packages?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think they have, and that's the source of the confusion: TO-247 is usually much better thermally than TO-220!

Comment: @Hearth That's exactly my confusion.

Comment: Could be electrical insulation between the body and the tab.  The SPP20N60S5 shows the tab as electrically connected to the drain.  The STW26NM60N doesn't indicate that the heat sink area is connected to anything so there might be insulation in there.  If you look at the datasheet, the STW26NM60N does have better pulse performance though.

Comment: Those max power ratings are at a case temperature of 25C, I believe. Do you think you can cool the case to 25C while dissipating 208W?

Answer (score 3):

Because of different packages, the other one can conduct heat away about 1.5 times better due to the thermal resistance, which enables it to it dissipate about 1.5 times more power.

In both packages, the Rtheta * Pmax is about the same, almost 125 degrees rise.

Comment: But what could be the reason for that better heat conduction? A larger silicon die, better connection or better epoxy compound?

Comment: It could be as simple as the smaller package has less epoxy on it. As you make the package smaller and smaller, you get closer and closer to the die. If you lower the temperature to 25C closer and closer to the die, you can dissipate more power.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you how P_TOT was calculated. It is just 125 / Rthj_case. The assumption built-in to P_TOT is that the case is at 25C. It is not very realistic to assume that the case will be at 25C when the transistor is dissipating over 100 Watts. So please keep that in mind.

Possibly it would be better to look at Rthja. Thermal resistance from junction to ambient. In the TO-249, that is given as 50 K/W with no footnote or explanation. In the TO-220 it is given as 62 K/W max for the minimum sized footprint, and 35 K/W typical for the large 6cm^2 footprint.

So depending on your layout, the thermal performance of the TO-249 might actually be better or the same. I guess the only conclusion you can draw from the P_TOT calculation is that the TO-220 has better thermal conductance to the case.

Probably the reason that the TO-220 has better thermal conductance to the surface of the case is just that the case is thinner/smaller. The case has thermal resistance and the thicker it is the higher that resistance will be (and the lower the conductance).

It is important to keep in mind what is going on when the die is at 150C and the case surface is at 25C. Heat is flowing through the plastic body and there is a strong temperature gradient (125C temp difference over a few mm). So in that extreme (and unrealistic) situation, the thinner the case, the more heat you can remove. If you take the thought experiment to its extreme conclusion, an infinitely thin case held at 25C would be the same as holding the die at 25C, and you could dissipate infinite power without overheating.

In general, the total power specifications for MOSFET's, when based on Tc of 25C are just about useless.